# Using Curl in Haskell Platform on Windows 7

Tags: haskell, curl, package, cabal

I'm trying to use 'import Text.XML.HXT.Curl' in my project so I can have access to online files (some xml files).

So the error I get is :

```
Could not find module `Text.XML.HXT.Curl':
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I tried :

```
:! cabal install curl
```

but I get an error that it must be on unix or cygwin, so I go on installing cygwin, now it says:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
curl-1.3.7 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77

:! gcc -version
Access is denied
```

I tried to download the curl package and install it with cmd : runHaskell Setup.hs configure but I get this :

```
Setup.hs: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
Missing C library: curl
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version)
```

Tried installing gcc,g++,libcurl,make in cygwin, still fails.

Tried installing mingw/mysis and I failed too. Something about curl/curl.h missing.

Does anyone succeeded and can tell me how he did it ?

Answer (score 2):

Installing `curl` on windows can be tricky. But you can try [hxt-http](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-http) package. It is based on native `HTTP` package, and doesn't require external dependencies. AFAIK it will just work out of the box on windows.

Small note: to use `curl` with `hxt`, you need to install [hxt-curl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-curl) package. But, yes, it will not help, cos it depends of `curl` package :(

So, my answer actually is about "using hxt on windows", not about "using curl on windows". You can ignore it in case it doesn't help you.